# Visual Studio Code: Get path in Javascript object

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have this Javascript object:

```
const user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'Jack',
        address: {
            line1: 'westwish st',
            line2: 'washmasher',
            city: 'wallas',
            state: 'WX'
        }
    }
}
```

From Visual Studio code I would like to be able to easily retrieve a path.

For example, by highlighting `city`, I would get this in the clipboard:

```
user.personalInfo.address.city;
```

Is it something feasible? I did not find any extension that could do it.